# Pointer arithmetic and dereferencing

Tags: c++

In the following code, can anyone please explain to my what the line in bold is doing.

```
struct southParkRec {
    int stan[4];
    int *kyle[4];
    int **kenny;
    string cartman;
};

int main()
{
    southParkRec cartoon;
    cartoon.stan[1] = 4;
    cartoon.kyle[0] = cartoon.stan + 1;
    cartoon.kenny = &cartoon.kyle[2];
    *(cartoon.kenny + 1) = cartoon.stan;  //What does this line do?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dude, where did you get this code? Any reason why Cartman gets the "bloated" object :) ?

Comment: I suspect he got it here: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106x/handouts/32-Section-Handout.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Think of it as

```
cartoon.kenny[1] = cartoon.stan;
```

They are basically the same thing

Answer (score 2):

If we bring the whole thing to one common style of using the subscript operator `[]` (possibly with `&`) instead of a `*` and `+` combination, it will look as follows

```
cartoon.stan[1] = 4;
cartoon.kyle[0] = &cartoon.stan[1];
cartoon.kenny = &cartoon.kyle[2];
cartoon.kenny[1] = &cartoon.stan[0];
```

After the

```
cartoon.kenny = &cartoon.kyle[2];
```

you can think of `kenny` as an "array" of `int *` elements embedded into the `kyle` array with 2 element offset: `kenny[0]` is equivalent to `kyle[2]`, `kenny[1]` is equivalent to `kyle[3]`, `kenny[2]` is equivalent to `kyle[4]` and so on.

So, when we do

```
cartoon.kenny[1] = &cartoon.stan[0];
```

it is equivalent to doing

```
cartoon.kyle[3] = &cartoon.stan[0];
```

That's basically what that last line does.

In other words, if we eliminate `kenny` from the consideration ("kill Kenny"), assuming that the rest of the code (if any) doesn't depend on it, your entire code will be equivalent to

```
cartoon.stan[1] = 4;
cartoon.kyle[0] = &cartoon.stan[1];
cartoon.kyle[3] = &cartoon.stan[0];
```

As for what is the point of all this... I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

In cartoon you have:
- stan, an array of 4 ints.
- kyle, an array of 4 pointers to int.
- kenny, a pointer to a pointer to int, that is, let's say, a pointer to an "array of ints".

`cartoon.stan[1] = 4;` sets second element of stan array (an int) to 1.
`cartoon.kyle[0] = cartoon.stan + 1;` sets first element of kyle array (a pointer to int) to point to the second element of stan array (which we have just set to 4).
`cartoon.kenny = &cartoon.kyle[2];` sets kenny pointer to point to the third element of kyle array.
`*(cartoon.kenny + 1) = cartoon.stan;` sets fourth element of kyle array (a pointer to int) to point to the first element of stan array (which hasn't been initialised yet). More in detail:

`cartoon.kenny` gets kenny pointer's address (third element of kyle array),
`cartoon.kenny+1` gets the next int after that address (fourth element of kyle array, which happens to be a pointer to int),
`*(cartoon.kenny + 1)` dereferences that pointer, so we can set it, and 
`= cartoon.stan` sets it to point to the first element of stan array.

Answer (score 0):

It is incrementing the pointer at *cartoon.kenny.  'kenny' is a pointer to a pointer, so the first dereference returns a pointer, which is incremented, and a value assigned.  So, *(kenny + 1) now points to the beginning of the array 'stan'.

Comment: I love when idiots vote people down to get their answer to the top.  What is wrong here exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It sets the last element of Kyle to point to the first element of Stan.